# openshift deletes assets

Tags: paperclip, openshift

How do I configure my models to avoid their assets being deleted upon assets recompilation, when I push new code to Openshift?

At the moment my model looks like this:

```
class Slide < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :caption, :position, :visible, :photo
  has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :thumb => "190x90>" }
  ...
```

I have noticed that uploaded photos are deleted from /public directory when Openshift recompiles my assets upon pushing new code.

I have found some old code looking like this:

```
has_attached_file :attachment, :removable  => true,
  :url => "/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  :path => ":rails_root/tmp/attachments/:id/:style/:basename.:extension"
```

Am I supposed to try something like in the above code snippet, or is there an option to change it in Openshift configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR structure will get replaced by your local git repo on every git push.

Best practice would be use $OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR instead of $OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR for handling uploads in your application.

For more details, please review: https://openshift.redhat.com/community/kb/kb-e1065-what-is-application-crud-and-how-should-i-handle-it-in-openshift